# How to convert any object to a byte array and keep it on memory?

Tags: python, arrays, byte, data-conversion

I'm trying to build a simple convertor for any object to byte array in Python. I took a look on `pickle` but it only works creating a file and this is not what I need. I also checked `json.dump` but some objects need a serializer to be dumped.

I need a convertor that keeps my object in memory and can convert any object to byte array.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#func-bytearray) function?

Comment: Yes, it seems like bytearray only convert strings to bytearray. Do you have an example in which I can convert any type of object to byte array @Abion47?

Comment: Any arbitrary type, no questions asked? No, and I don't believe it is possible without some serious reflection work, and even then it's debatably more trouble than its worth. If you want to serialize a type (especially a custom type), you typically have to define how it can be serialized (e.g. by conforming to the [buffer interface](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) so you can serialize it with `bytearray`).

Comment: To talk about pickle, though, what makes you think it only works by writing it to files? Have you tried the `dumps` function?

Comment: Hmmm maybe this can help me, I'll try to implement it but to be honest I was really searching for an whatever-to-bytearray converter as you mentioned. It's tragic because we can easily do that in other languages :( but thanks man.

Comment: @R.Karlus you can use `pickle.dumps`, but *why* do you need to convert it into `bytes`? What is the purpose?

Comment: There are other languages where this kind of serialization is baked into the language itself, but those languages usually have other trade-offs for the feature. There are also languages that support the reflection way where someone else has already done the heavy lifting. For python, as far as I know, pickle is as good as it gets.

Comment: But you should probably ask yourself why you are doing this. Is it for a specific purpose or just for convenience? If its the latter, then my best advice to you is to stop looking for a shortcut and just do the leg work. It won't get any easier for you to use some library that seems like it does what you want but you don't actually understand.

Comment: There's a third-party module named [`dill`](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) which is similar to `pickle` but can serialize more (most? all?) things. It conforms to the `pickle` interface, so has a `dumps()` method that returns a `bytes` object.

Comment: You guys are awesome. I could solve the problem with `pickle.dumps`. Thanks a lot @Abion47

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm adding this as an actual answer since it seemed to address your needs. Your use of `pickle.dump` is the problem since it is designed to take the serialized object and write it to a file (though as pointed out in other answers, it doesn't necessarily have to, but that's beside the point).

The function you want to be using is [`pickle.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps), which returns the serialized object directly as a byte array:

```py
someobject = 123
someobject_bytes = pickle.dumps(someobject)
```

Comment: Awesome! Fantastic! Voted up.

Comment: pickle.loads(someobject_bytes) to deserialized the bytes

Answer (score 1):

The `file` parameter to `Pickler` just needs to have a `write(b)` method that receives the bytes. In principle you can write your own class with your method `write(self,b)` that does whatever you want with those bites and pass an object of that class to `Pickler`

Example:

```
import pickle

class File:
  def write(self,b):
    print(b)

f = File()
p = pickle.Pickler(f)

object = 3.14
p.dump(object)
```

Output: `b'\x80\x03G@\t\x1e\xb8Q\xeb\x85\x1f.'`

Instead of printing the bytes, like in this example, you could append them in a `list`, or anything else you want.

Comment: This is a lot of work to make `dump` work when you can just use `dumps`.

Comment: I solved the problem using pickle dumps method. But here is my upvote for the help.

Comment: @Abion47 This is not 'to make `dump` work', but to show that it doesn't have to be a file when it is used. The two forms of delivering values, as a return value or as a callback have their cases in which one is more preferable than the other.

Comment: Sure, you can use `dump` with something that isn't a file object. But you have to define a custom class that adheres to a specific interface that defines a function which receives the bytes as a parameter. Or... you can skip all that and get the bytes directly using `dumps`. Your answer is an interesting factoid, but I am unable to think of a situation where it would actually be a useful alternative solution for OP.

Comment: @Abion47 There should be many posts online where you can learn when using callbacks rather than return values is more convenient. [This one](https://code-maven.com/function-or-callback-in-python) is one. I can think of some: The serialization doesn't fit in memory and you want to do something with it, like compare it to another, for example.

Comment: How would this approach address the issue of not being able to fit the entire serialization in memory? You are still getting the entire bytes array passed into the parameter. And yes, there are times that callbacks are more useful than simple returns (though your linked example is extremely contrived), but that is irrelevant to OP's question.

Comment: @Abion47 I think you should ask a separate question if you want to learn how to. Since I am getting the impression that your questions are more challenges than genuine questions, I am not tempted to put the time in doing the work for you. About answering the OP, my answer is directed, clearly, to the part in where they said "but it only works creating a file" and only that part. So, I explained how this is not necessarily the case. You seem to feel that somehow return value is a superior method. Enjoy. It is somewhat misguided, though, since it depends on what you want to do. But be happy.

Comment: The reason I am challenging your answer is that while it may have broader use cases that I haven't considered, those are irrelevant to OP's needs. OP asked for a method that takes an object and returns a byte array. You can spend time telling him how to tweak the behavior of pickle to make `dump` "return" a byte array. Or you can tell him to use `dumps` since that's literally what it was designed to do. Your answer, while technically an answer, is fixated on a specific statement rather than the actual question, and as such is tangential to the simple answer which is all OP needs.

Comment: @Abion47 Well, as I said, I am not interested in your challenge. Maybe you should also learn, that the answers in this website are not only for the original person that posted the question, but also to anyone else that passes by. If you have some itch, you can: Post a comment, post an answer, even edit my answer. Your fixation on `dumps` vs `dump`, and whether accidentally one ends up being the one that the person that asked the question, in their judgment or misjudgment, prefers using, is insubstantial. If that represents a victory that you feel you need to feel worthy. Have it. You win.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216673/discussion-between-abion47-and-notdijkstra).