# Change any type to bytes in python

Tags: python, byte

In python you can change any type in python to a string like this:

```py
str(data)
```

Is there a way to change any type to bytes exactly like the `str(data)` method? (without if statements)?

Something like `bytes(data)`:

```py
# examples
data = "hello"
data = bytes(data) # data is now b'hello'

data = 23423
data = bytes(data) # data is now b'23423'

data = b'nice'
data = bytes(data) # data is now b'nice'

data = [0, 3]
data = bytes(data) # data is now b'[0, 3]'
```

Using `str(data).encode()` or `bytes(str(value), "utf-8")` is not what i'm looking for because when the data `data = b'dsfsdf'` the output is `b"b'dsfsdf'"`.

Comment: `bytes(str(value), "utf-8")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert any object to a byte array and keep it on memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62565944/how-to-convert-any-object-to-a-byte-array-and-keep-it-on-memory)

Comment: @Martheen I'm trying without importing libraries

Comment: @OlvinRoght When using on `data = b'dsfsdf'` the output is `b"b'dsfsdf'"`. Not what i'm looking for.

Comment: `str(obj).encode()`?

Comment: @lordcommander, this wasn't in your question.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Sorry now I edited

Comment: There is no built-in function that does exactly what you want. You basically want `data if isinstance(data, bytes) else str(data).encode()`

Comment: may I ask why you want it your data to be stored as byte?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You actually had a point in your first comment. Thank you for your answer in the second comment, I think thats the best option

Comment: @AagamSheth It's for an encryption

Comment: What exactly are you doing with those bytes? What is the purpose of getting the string representation of an object and then converting to bytes (unless you have bytes already)?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I actually don't care for objects, I just want to handle every possible input and convert it to bytes instead of raising an error message

Comment: @lordcommander, if you need to encrypt any data and restore them back without any problems, just use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: @lordcommander what do you mean "I actually don't care for objects", *everything* is an object... including `bytes` objects. But again, *what is the purpose of converting to a string representation of an object?* Are you actually trying to *serialize* an object, to be able to deserialize it later? Because then you shouldn't do this.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Ok I'll try that

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I meant lists, tuple etc. I'm just trying to change it to bytes so it will be able to get encrypted

Comment: You still aren't being totally clear, but from what I can gather, I think you *absolutely don't want what you describing above*. You require a *serialization format*, like `pickle`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm sorry english isn't my first language, i'll try using pickle. I'm not trying to deserialize it later, just convert to bytes

Answer (score 0):

When you call `str(data)` for a custom object, it is basically calling `data.__str__()`, so by giving your object a `__str__` method you can specify exactly what `str(data)` actually going to look like. For `bytes(data)` you just need to implement `__bytes__`:

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:   def __bytes__(self):
   ...:     return b"A"

In [2]: bytes(A())[0] == 65
Out[2]: True

In [3]: bytes(A())
Out[3]: b'A'

In [4]: str(A())
Out[4]: "<class '__main__.A'>"
```

To handle basic types in your example, if you're happy with their string representation, you can just do:

```
def to_bytes(x):
  return x if isinstance(x, bytes) else str(x).encode()
```

If you want something more robust, use a serialization library like [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Answer (score 0):

As there are suggestions in the comment about using the `pickle` package to serialize, here is the code to perform it

```
import pickle

data = "hello"
byte_data = pickle.dumps(data)
print(pickle.loads(byte_data))

data = 23423
byte_data = pickle.dumps(data)
print(pickle.loads(byte_data))

data = b'nice'
byte_data = pickle.dumps(data)
print(pickle.loads(byte_data))

data = [0, 3]
byte_data = pickle.dumps(data)
print(pickle.loads(byte_data))

output :
hello
23423
b'nice'
[0, 3]
```

ps: credits to [Olvin Roght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10824407/olvin-roght) for suggesting to use pickle