# Where is the problem when I try to changed the class string to bytes in python?

Tags: python, odoo

```
def write(self,vals):
        for record in self:
            
            emp_id = record.employee_name
            user = self.env['res.users'].search([("email",'=',record.mail)])
            if vals.get('unit_icon'):

                if vals.get('unit_name'):
                   
                    members = self.env['team.works'].search([('unit_name.id','=',vals.get('unit_name'))])
                else:
                    members = self.env['team.works'].search([('unit_name.id','=',record.unit_name['id'])])
                    #print("---------------------------1")
                    #print(type(vals.get('unit_icon')))
                    b = bytes(vals.get('unit_icon'), 'utf-8') #This line the give the error
                    #print(b)
                    #print("---------------------------2")
                    for i in members:
                        #print("---------------------------3")
                        #print(type(i['unit_icon']))
                        #print(i['unit_icon'])
                        i['unit_icon'] = b
                        #print("---------------------------4")
```

Hi everyone. I am working on the in odoo project.If the logo is changed, I want to updated logo of other members but there is a problem.Changed logo class is a string.[Updated logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ5SQ.jpg) other members logo class is bytes [other member logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmTTa.jpg).I am trying to string to bytes to achive this

```
b = bytes(vals.get('unit_icon'), 'utf-8')
```

[After changed class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ophyl.jpg) but it give me the error "TypeError: encoding without a string argument". What is the problem of the code ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert any object to a byte array and keep it on memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62565944/how-to-convert-any-object-to-a-byte-array-and-keep-it-on-memory)

Comment: It converted [link](https://imgur.com/a/SQWW7hi).This is not I wanted

Comment: probably `vals.get('unit_icon')` is returning `None` because the key `unit_icon` is not present

Comment: No `vals.get('unit_icon')` returning as a string [link](https://imgur.com/a/4jaGJ0M)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if vals.get('unit_icon') is string then Pythonic way is:

```
b = vals.get('unit_icon').encode()  # encode defaults to 'utf-8'
```